# iPhone: Disable vibration for all notifications except for phone calls

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I disable vibrations for all notifications except for phone calls on an iPhone? This is for an iPhone 6 running iOS 8.

For instance, if I receive a notification such as a new email, my phone vibrates. And when I get phone calls, my phone vibrates. But when I disable vibration, it disables vibration for both notifications and phone calls.

So I'd like to separate the two, so that I don't get vibrations for notifications, but I do get vibrations for phone calls.

Is there a way to do this, without needing to enable vibrations and disabling vibrations on an app-by-app basis?

Answer (score 8):

You can turn off vibrations for individual events from Settings > Sounds.

[image]
[image]
[image]

You can turn them all off, turn off all but Ringtone (receiving phone calls), or keep them all on.

**Note:** Any events that are not listed here can be turned off from the apps that produce them.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to go to iPhone Settings > Notifications and modify the settings for each app so that Vibration is set to None.

Comment: I don't see an option for Vibration for apps in Notifications. I think "Sound" will achieve this instead?

Comment: My mistake: I was basing my answer of the settings for Mail, since I was already in there. But Mail is unique, I see now that most apps do not let you set the vibration independently of the sound.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like most of the search results that come up specifically refer to Mail... but I'm interested in all apps. And I use the Gmail app rather than the Mail app for my emails, anyway. I think the "Sound" setting is tied to "Vibration" for most apps.